# error: reference to overloaded function could not be resolved

Tags: c++, c++11, c++17

The following code:

```
struct A
{
    using this_t = A;
    template <class F1>
    void ins(const F1& fu)
    {
    }
    template <class F1, class... Args>
    void ins(const F1& fu, const Args&... args)
    {
        this_t::ins<Args...>(args...);
        // the line which is causing the error:
        constexpr decltype(&this_t::ins<Args...>) func = &this_t::ins<Args...>;
    }
};
int main()
{
    A a;
    a.ins(5, 5, 5, 5, 5);
}
```

Gives this error:

```
error: reference to overloaded function could not be resolved
```

As shown here: https://godbolt.org/z/nJiY4A

What's going wrong here and how is it possible to get the pointer to the function then?

Comment: Both versions of `ins` could be called with one argument. So once the recursion gets down to `ins(5)`, the call is ambiguous. One way to solve that would be to have the first overload take no parameters (and not be a template).

Comment: @IgorTandetnik It doesn't appear to be ambiguous: https://godbolt.org/z/oe6e3A

Comment: @IgorTandetnik - "One way to solve that would be to have the first overload take no parameters (and not be a template)." - this works when the call doesn't explicit the `<Args...>` template arguments; in this case, the no-arguments ground case has to be a template function with a different (not a type, maybe a value) template parameter with a default value; this way can intercept the `ins<>()` call.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think I know why that line fails to compile. It has little to do with overload resolution, and everything to do with `decltype`:

> **[over.over]/1** A use of an overloaded function name without arguments is resolved in certain contexts to a function, a pointer to function or a pointer to member function for a specific function from the overload set. A function template name is considered to name a set of overloaded functions in such contexts. A function with type `F` is selected for the function type `FT` of the target type required in the context if `F` (after possibly applying the function pointer conversion (7.13)) is identical to `FT`. The target can be
>
> (1.1) — an object or reference being initialized (11.6, 11.6.3, 11.6.4),
>   (1.2) — the left side of an assignment (8.18),
>   (1.3) — a parameter of a function (8.2.2),
>   (1.4) — a parameter of a user-defined operator (16.5),
>   (1.5) — the return value of a function, operator function, or conversion (9.6.3),
>   (1.6) — an explicit type conversion (8.2.3, 8.2.9, 8.4), or
>   (1.7) — a non-type template-parameter (17.3.2).
>
> The overloaded function name can be preceded by the & operator. **An overloaded function name shall not be used without arguments in contexts other than those listed.**

Emphasis mine. Just mentioning an overloaded function name outside of those enumerated contexts - e.g. in `decltype(&this_t::ins<F2, Args...>)` - renders the program ill-formed. Avoiding this problematic usage by spelling the type explicitly [makes the code compile](https://rextester.com/KVB70098):

```
    void (this_t::*func)(const Args&...) = &this_t::ins<Args...>;
```

Comment: And it seems the big three compilers agree that a template-id is not "an overloaded function name" if multiple function templates have the name but template argument deduction (without function arguments) and substitution succeed for exactly one function template: https://godbolt.org/z/VRDj44 I haven't found anything in the Standard that clarifies this sort of case.

Comment: @aschepler maybe those compilers implement newer drafts, where [over.over]p1 has been substantially reworded and allows usage of overloaded function names in contexts other than those listed . And then there's http://eel.is/c++draft/temp.arg.explicit#4.sentence-4 which has existed for a long time.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not yet sure why taking an address of the overloaded function behaves differently than calling it; why the former produces an ambiguity while the latter is able to resolve the overload successfully.

Meanwhile, here's one possible workaround:

```
struct A
{
    using this_t = A;
    template <class F1>
    void ins(const F1& fu)
    {
    }
    template <class F1, class F2, class... Args>
    void ins(const F1& f1, const F2& f2, const Args&... args)
    {
        this_t::ins<F2, Args...>(f2, args...);
        // the line which is causing the error:
        constexpr decltype(&this_t::ins<F2, Args...>) func = &this_t::ins<F2, Args...>;
    }
};
```

The tweak is to make the first overload callable with one argument, and the second with two or more. [Demo](https://rextester.com/EGP63810)

Comment: Thank you, your workaround seems to work. Despite of the behaviour looks very strange to me.

Comment: "I'm not yet sure why taking an address of the overloaded function behaves differently than calling it" Why? Isn't that supposed to be obvious? When you call a function, you supply *arguments*, which are used to resolve the overload. When you take the address, you don't supply any arguments.

Comment: @AnT The line of code where the address is taken explicitly specifies template parameters. On the surface, it seems that should provide the same or better information to the compiler than argument deduction.

Answer (score 0):

Not exactly what you asked but... if you can use an empty (do nothing, nothing receiving) ground recursion case, I propose the following solution

```
struct A
{
    using this_t = A;

    template <int = 0>
    void ins ()
     { }

    template <typename F1, typename ... Args>
    void ins (F1 const &, Args const & ... args)
    {
        this_t::ins<Args...>(args...);

        // no more error
        constexpr decltype(&this_t::ins<Args...>) func = &this_t::ins<Args...>;
    }
};
```

This way, calling `ins<Args...>`, you can avoid all ambiguities when `Args...` is only one type (only the recursion case matches) and when `Args...` is empty, matches the ground case thanks to the `int = 0` template default value.